# App crashes when i press the button

Tags: java, android

My app crashes as soon as i press the button "Lets's Play".
I just started developing.. and its not even the text that makes the error, i tried only to do tv1.setText("test"); and it crashed too.

here is my code :

```
    package com.example.adam.casinoadam;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {

    ImageView iv1;
    ImageView iv2;
    ImageView iv3;
    TextView tv1;
    Button btn1;
    int x,y,z;
    int coins=15;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    public void Start(View view) {
        if(coins==0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry. Good Bye!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        coins=coins-1;
        tv1.setText("Money: "+coins+" Coins");


        x=1+(int)((5-1+1)*Math.random());
        y=1+(int)((5-1+1)*Math.random());
        z=1+(int)((5-1+1)*Math.random());


        if(x==1)iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cherry);
        if(x==2)iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiltan);
        if(x==3)iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell);


        if(y==1)iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.cherry);
        if(y==1)iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiltan);
        if(y==1)iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell);


        if(z==1)iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.cherry);
        if(z==1)iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiltan);
        if(z==1)iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.bell);


        if(x==y && y==z && z==x){
            Toast.makeText(this,"You won !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            coins=coins+10;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Try moving all findViewById after setContentView  (onCreate method)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your onCreate with below code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);1
}
```

> `findViewById()` returns a View if it exists in the layout you provided
>   in `setContentView()`, otherwise it returns `null` and that's what
>   happening to you.
>
> If you `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
>   and then call `findViewById(R.id.iv1);` it will return a View which
>   is your layout, But if you call `findViewById(R.id.iv1);` before
>   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` it will return `null` since
>   there is no view attached to your activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't initialize the view objects before setContentView called in onCreate method. If you initialize the view objects it will get null values because the activity doesnot get it's layout file.

```
iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

These 5 lines must be after these two lines in onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

So, your code must be :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
        iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    }
```

**findViewById** must be after **setContentView**

Answer (score 0):

You must define the views after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this `onCreate()` First you have to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` befor casting your `Button` and all.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

So at last your code look like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try doing this because until the layout is defined by `contentview` you cant use (`findviewbyid`) function in the program

```
  @Override

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);
    iv2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv2);
    iv3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv3);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);

}
```